Graph API - Add ListeItem containing multiple values in managed metadata column
I'm trying to add a ListItem to an SPFx list using the Graph API. The column is a managed metadata type that allows multiple values. I'm able to add one value, but can't figure out how to add multiple. In my example below I get a 400 Bad Request response. It seems to not like the square brackets.
The API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items

400 Bad Request:
{
  "fields": {
    "{termColumnName}": [
      "-1;{termLabel1}|{termGuid1}", 
      "-1;{termLabel2}|{termGuid2}"
    ]
  }
}

200 Success - but only term 2 gets populated in the column
{
  "fields": {
    "{termColumnName}": "-1;{termLabel1}|{termGuid1}, -1;{termLabel2}|{termGuid2}"
  }
}

Does anyone know how to format this for multiple values?

Could you try to format the values like this: "{termLabel1}|{termGuid1};{termLabel2}|{termGuid2}"? Example: "software engineer|5e6730d0-86bf-4913-bfa3-f7369e5bade4;team leader|123abcd0-86bf-4913-bfa3-abc1235bade4"

I wouuld recommend you to post batch requests
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch

Here is the document for details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0
